# How to resolve "recyclerView must not be null"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to Implement **Recycler View** in Activity after parsing data using Retrofit.But the problem is it shows Recycler view cannot be null even after initializing inside **onCreate** method before accessing.

***Mainactitivty.kt***

```
        class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        lateinit var myRecyclerView: RecyclerView

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        retroInstance = RetroInstance()
        val instance = retroInstance.getInstance()
        val api = instance.create(RetroInterface::class.java)
        val callAll=api.getAllDetail()
    callAll.enqueue(object :retrofit2.Callback<ModelAll>{
           override fun onFailure(call: Call<ModelAll>, t: Throwable) {
               Toast.makeText(applicationContext,t.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           }

           override fun onResponse(call: Call<ModelAll>, response: Response<ModelAll>) {
               val allDetail=response.body()!!
                myRecyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
              myRecyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
               myRecyclerView.adapter=CoronaAdapter(allDetail)
           }

       })
    }
  }
```

*Activity with recycler view included*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AllCountries">


    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_search"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:queryHint="Search here..."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***Logcat***
https://gist.github.com/devpawann/af3cef9d204a6f99cd7ed11937684fa2

*EDIT*:- Issue solved, the mistake was that I initializes recycler view in another activity class

Comment: can you show us your activity_main.xml?

Comment: @ConfusedPup I have updated it.

Comment: this is indeed very weird are you sure that you are importing correct recyclerView? try call it outside of OnResponse or check if seatchView is too null

Comment: @ConfusedPup yes it shows the same outside of OnResponse too

Comment: can you put your error logcat

Comment: @UpendraShah it is mentioned in last part of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe try something like this:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private var allDetails: MutableList<ModelAll> = ArrayList()

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        retroInstance = RetroInstance()
        val instance = retroInstance.getInstance()
        val api = instance.create(RetroInterface::class.java)
        val callAll=api.getAllDetail()


        //Init your recyclerview
        val myRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        myRecyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val coronaAdapter = CoronaAdapter(allDetails)
        myRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        callAll.enqueue(object :retrofit2.Callback<ModelAll>{
           override fun onFailure(call: Call<ModelAll>, t: Throwable) {
               Toast.makeText(applicationContext,t.message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
           }

           override fun onResponse(call: Call<ModelAll>, response: Response<ModelAll>) {
               if(response.isSucessful()){
                    allDetails = response.body()!!
                    coronaAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
               }
           }

       })
}
```

EDIT: The issue was that the `recyclerView` was in another layout that the one inflated.

Comment: Still same error on line `val myRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)`

Comment: can you add the logcat in your post? not just one line

Comment: https://gist.github.com/devpawann/af3cef9d204a6f99cd7ed11937684fa2
I was not able to modify the question so please refer form here

Comment: Are you sure you're inflating the right layout ? It seems your `recyclerview` isn't in `activity_main `

Comment: Yes irecycler view is on another activity and I am refering that same in findviewbyID

Comment: I didn't understand :/ You have 2 recyclerview with the same id ?

Comment: I am extremy sorry I initializes the recycler view in another class :(

Answer (score 1):

Your recyclerView has not been **instantiated**(currently it is referring to **null**).

Add this line

```
 recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
```

Or if you are using **Android Extensions** then make sure you are using correct recyclerview

Comment: In that case, you have not instantiated the recycler view.. Make your **recyclerView variable an instance variable, initiallize it in oncreate using recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)**

Comment: now its showing `java.lang.IllegalStateException: findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) must not be null`

Comment: It is saying the same.Your recyclerview is referring to **null**.. Try adding ```recyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)``` before                                         
 ``` recyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity) ```

Comment: Please post the new change you did

Comment: I have updated the change. If this helps, I have these all codes for recyclerview layout manager in another function which is called form onCreate method.

Comment: Initialize your recyclerview and adapter in oncreate before this line ```callAll.enqueue``` and in onResponse, get the response object and pass it to your model and call ```notifyDataSetChanged```